# How to enforce tls 1.x using wininet

Tags: c++, ssl, wininet, winhttp

I'm using wininet library in my aplication, after it turned out that sslv3 loooves poodle, some websites turn it off, and my aplication does not working on some PC's unless user set in Internet settings in windows to use TLS 1.X. Does anyone know way to force wininet to use tls 1.x connection ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wininet uses schannel.dll for the SSL/TLS communication and will automatically negotiate TLS if the server side offers TLS.  There is nothing for you to do.

I should add that TLS support varies based on Windows version. For up to date TLS support, the minimum Windows versions are Win 7 and Win 2008 R2.

Detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kaushal/support-for-ssltls-protocols-on-windows